# problems loading local html file from assets folder

Tags: android, listview, webview

I'm trying to load html file from assets folder on listview item click.
the problem is, on click it shows the clean page, inspect of html file.
here is a fragment of code.

```
public static ListView listview;
    public static ArrayList<String> interviews;
    public static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    public WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kochergin);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    //  myWebView = new WebView(this);
        listview.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        listview.setCacheColorHint(Color.BLACK);

        String[] interviewlist = new String[] {"Interview1", "Interview2","Interview3","Interview4","Interview5","Interview6"};  
        ArrayList<String> interviews = new ArrayList<String>();
        interviews.addAll( Arrays.asList(interviewlist) );


        ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, R.id.rowTextView, interviews);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        Collections.sort(interviews);


    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
        {

            setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        //  myWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           //   myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/2.html");
        }
    });
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: on which version of android are your running it?

Comment: the program is on API level 17

Comment: remove the setContentView inside the onItemClick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are loading the URL to `myWebView` which is in `R.layout.activity_kochergin` and not in `R.layout.webview` which you are setting as Activity's Content View in `onItemClick`.

So remove the `setContentView(R.layout.webview);` from `onItemClick` and it will work.

**UPDATE**

change the `setOnItemClickListener` to:-

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
        {

            setContentView(R.layout.webview);
            myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/2.html");
        }
    });
```

Comment: so it means your `R.id.webview` is in `R.layout.webview` and not in `R.layout.activity_kochergin`..check my update.

Comment: Thanks for your update, but not I got "the file requested was not found".

Comment: check for the 2.html in assets folder..is it in the assets folder or u've created an another folder in assets...

Comment: It is directly in assets folder, I also tried to load another html file, but result is same .. 
http://www.dropbox.com/s/xt3cx7fuolps65j/SC20130526-123500.png

Comment: don't mind..but check that u hav given the name of the folder as **assets** and not **asset**.

Comment: the problem is that file extension is .htm and not .html